# I get null as the value referring to the radio button

Tags: javascript

I need to set the radio Button to the value I pass via url.

```js
function filterCategory(ads) {
  let categories = Array.from(new Set(ads.map(ann => ann.category)));

  let rowCategoryRadio = document.querySelector('#row-category-radio');

  categories.forEach((cat, i) => {

    let input = document.createElement('div');

    input.classList.add('form-check');

    input.innerHTML = `
        <input class="form-check-input filter-category" type="radio" name="category-filter" id="flexRadioDefault${i}" data-filter="${cat}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault${i}">
        ${cat}
        </label>
        `
    rowCategoryRadio.appendChild(input);
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="row-category-radio">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input filter-category" type="radio" name="category-filter" id="flexRadioDefault1" data-filter="all" checked>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                        All categories
                      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

To set the radio button to the value I step I wrote the following code, just that I'm getting the value of selected **null**

```js
let url_string = window.location.href;
let url2 = new URL(url_string);
let name_url = url2.searchParams.get("name");

let radios = document.querySelector('.filter-category');
let selected = radios.querySelector(`[data-filter="${name_url}"]`);
selected.checked = true;;
console.log(selected);
```

Can anyone kindly help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`radios.querySelector()` searches for elements nested within `radios` that match the selector. But the `data-filter` attribute is on the `radios` element itself, not a nested element.

You want to put these into a single query selector.

```
let selected = document.querySelector(`.filter-category[data-filter="${name_url}"]`)
```

Comment: Can you answer this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72537869/change-value-of-select-and-radio-button-together?noredirect=1#comment128137802_72537869