# Change value of select and radio button together

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have the value of the select and the value of the radio button on the same value? I'll explain.

What I want to get is that when the select changes it also changes (automatically) the radio button value to the same value in which the select is selected and vice versa (i.e. the value of the select to the same value in which the radio button is selected).

```js
function filterCategoryRadio(ads) {
  let radios = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-category');
  radios.forEach(radio => {
    radio.addEventListener('input', function() {
      let selected = radio.getAttribute('data-filter');
      if (selected == "all") {
        listAds(ads);
      } else {
        let filtered = ads.filter(ann => ann.category == selected)
        //console.log(filtered);
        listAds(filtered);
      }
    })
  })
}

function filterCategorySelect(ads) {
  let input = document.querySelector('#category-select');

  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (input.value == "all") {
      listAds(ads);
    } else {
      let filtered = ads.filter(ann => ann.category == input.value)
      listAds(filtered);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-body">
  <div class="row mt-2 mb-4">
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="category-select">
      <option value="all" selected>All category</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row-category-radio">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input filter-category" type="radio" name="category-filter" id="flexRadioDefault1" data-filter="all" checked>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
        All category
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What you want is doable. However, what you posted is missing needed code. Like the function and data for **listAds**. Also side notes. for radio events, just use **change** instead of **input**.

Comment: @imvain2 listAds is a function that returns the cards related to the ads. I am failing to understand

Comment: I would check out this article [mcve]

Comment: Can't demonstrate a working and useful answer if we don't have some data relevant to the question. I'm not going to waste my time or yours guessing what you have or don't have.

Comment: Why have both a radio and select if they're always set to the same thing?

Comment: There's only one radio button, what's the point of that? And the select only has one option. There's stuff missing here.

Comment: because unfortunately I was asked to do this. I couldn't do otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `click` event on the radio button, not `input`. When you click on a button, set the value of the `select` to the button's value (normally this is in the `value` attribute, but you're using `data-filter` instead).

And when you change the value of the `select`, use its value to select to corresponding radio button, and set its `check` property to choose it.

```js
function filterCategoryRadio(ads) {
  let radios = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-category');
  radios.forEach(radio => {
    radio.addEventListener('click', function() {
      let selected = radio.getAttribute('data-filter');
      document.querySelector("#category-select").value = selected;
      if (selected == "all") {
        listAds(ads);
      } else {
        let filtered = ads.filter(ann => ann.category == selected)
        //console.log(filtered);
        listAds(filtered);
      }
    })
  })
}

function filterCategorySelect(ads) {
  let input = document.querySelector('#category-select');

  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (input.value == "all") {
      listAds(ads);
    } else {
      let filtered = ads.filter(ann => ann.category == input.value)
      listAds(filtered);
    }
    document.querySelector(`.filter-category[data-filter="${input.value}"]`).checked = true;
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-body">
  <div class="row mt-2 mb-4">
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="category-select">
      <option value="all" selected>All category</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row-category-radio">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input filter-category" type="radio" name="category-filter" id="flexRadioDefault1" data-filter="all" checked>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
        All category
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```